# How to set a unique URL placeholder to every new URL input added

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Look at this form and tell me
How to set a unique placeholder to every new input added by the function.  I want to replace the placeholder value with the string "Product" + counter.

```
<html>
<input class="name" type='text' placeholder="First name" required>
        <input class="name" type='text' placeholder="Last name" required><br>
        <input type="email" placeholder="example@mail.com" required><br>
        <div id="url">
        </div>
        <button id="bu">add Products urls</button>
</html>

<script>
var url = document.getElementById('url'),
    counter = 1,
    but = document.getElementById('bu');

but.onclick = function () {
  'use strict';
   url.innerHTML += 'Product' + counter + ' <input type="url" placeholder="url">
   <br>';
    counter++;
};
</script>
```

Comment: Your `<script>` should be inside the `<html>` block, not outside. Also, you're missing a `<head>` and `<body>`. Not sure if it matters or is relevant to your question.

Comment: what you mean by unique url? like a server url

Comment: One problem is that you have a line break in your code.  `url.innerHTML += 'Product' + counter + ' <input type="url" placeholder="url"><br>';` should be all on the same line.

Comment: No, That's not my problem, I wrote the code correctly in my folder and it's running normally but I want to know how to change the placeholder in every new URL input added after someone click on the button.

Answer (score 0):

To update the placeholder, just concat the string and counter (or whatever string you want) as the value of placeholder attribute:

```
var url = document.getElementById('url'),
    counter = 1,
    but = document.getElementById('bu');

but.onclick = function () {
  'use strict';
  var placeholder = 'Product' + counter;
   url.innerHTML += placeholder + ' <input type="url" placeholder="' + placeholder +'"><br>';
    counter++;
};
```

Comment: Exactly, That's what I was looking for, Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var url = document.getElementById('url');
var counter = 1;
var but = document.getElementById('bu');

but.onclick = function() {
  'use strict';
  
  url.innerHTML += 'Product' + counter + ' <input type="url" placeholder="URL No '+counter+'"> <br > ';
  counter++;
};
```

```html
<input class="name" type='text' placeholder="First name" required>
<input class="name" type='text' placeholder="Last name" required><br>
<input type="email" placeholder="example@mail.com" required><br>
<div id="url">
</div>
<button id="bu">add Products urls</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  var url = document.getElementById('url'),
    counter = 1,
    but = document.getElementById('bu');
 
 //Say you have array with list of urls 
 var arr = ["http://alloy.liferay.com/deploy/api", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/index.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_aui-autocomplete.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_aui-button-item.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_aui-calendar.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_aui-char-counter.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_aui-color-picker.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_aui-component.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_aui-datatype.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_aui-delayed-task.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_aui-dialog.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_aui-editable.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_aui-event.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_aui-image-viewer.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_aui-io.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_aui-live-search.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_aui-loading-mask.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_aui-nested-list.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_aui-node.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_aui-overlay.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_aui-paginator.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_aui-panel.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_aui-parse-content.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_aui-portal-layout.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_aui-progressbar.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_aui-rating.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_aui-resize.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_aui-textboxlist.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_aui-toolbar.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_aui-tooltip.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_aui-tree.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_align-plugin.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_anim.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_async-queue.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_attribute.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_base.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_cache.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_classnamemanager.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_collection.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_console.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_console-filters.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_cookie.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_dataschema.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_datasource.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_datatype.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_dd.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_dom.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_dump.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_event.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_event-custom.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_event-simulate.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_history.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_imageloader.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_intl.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_io.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_json.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_loader.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_node.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_node-focusmanager.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_node-menunav.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_oop.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_overlay.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_plugin.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_pluginhost.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_profiler.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_querystring.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_queue-promote.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_shim-plugin.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_slider.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_sortable.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_stylesheet.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_substitute.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_swf.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_swfdetect.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_tabview.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_test.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_widget.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_widget-anim.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_widget-parent.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_widget-position.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_widget-position-align.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_widget-position-constrain.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_widget-stack.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_widget-stdmod.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/module_yui.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/A.HTML5.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/A.io.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/A.Node.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/A.NodeList.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/A.Plugin.IO.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/Anim.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/Array.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/ArrayList.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/ArrayList~add.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/ArrayList~filter.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/Assert.ArrayAssert.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/Assert.ComparisonFailure.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/Assert.DateAssert.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/Assert.Error.html", "https://alloyui.com/versions/1.0.x/api/Assert.ObjectAssert.html"]

but.onclick = function() {
  'use strict';
  url.innerHTML += 'Product ' + counter + ' <input type="text" placeholder='+ arr[counter]+' /> <br/>';
  counter++;
};
```

```html
<input class="name" type='text' placeholder="First name" required>
<input class="name" type='text' placeholder="Last name" required>
<br>
<input type="email" placeholder="example@mail.com" required>
<button id="bu">add Products urls</button>
<br>
<div id="url">
</div>
```